A similar formula for pushforward of inversion map on Lie groupoid
If $G$ is a Lie group with inversion $\iota$, it is well-known that the differential at the identity $e$ of $\iota$ is given by
$$\iota_{*e}:T_eG\to T_eG,\,\iota_{*e}(X_e)=-X_e.$$
I am wonedring whether there is a similar formula on Lie groupoids.
Given a Lie groupoid $\Gamma\rightrightarrows P,$ with source and target given by $s,t:\Gamma\to P.$ Let $$\Gamma_2=\{(x,y)\in \Gamma\times\Gamma\,|\,s(x)=t(y)\}$$
be the space of composable sequence. Let $m:\Gamma_2\to \Gamma$ be the groupoid multiplication. And let $i:\Gamma\to\Gamma$ be the inversion map, let $\varepsilon:P\to \Gamma$ be the unit map.
Let $g\in \Gamma.$ The inversion map is $i:s^{-1}(t(g))\to t^{-1}(t(g))=t^{-1}(s(g^{-1})).$
So
$$i_*:T_{t(g)}(s^{-1}(t(g)))\to T_{s(g^{-1})}(t^{-1}(s(g^{-1}))).$$
For $\,X\in T_{t(g)}(s^{-1}(t(g))),$ is it the correct formula that $i_*(X_{t(g)})=-X_{s(g^{-1})}$? How to prove it? Or how to prove the correct statement? Thanks in advance!
